# Prove two operators commute and a further question

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators, differential-operators

Let $\psi,\varphi\in L^2(-1,1),$ and $\lambda,\chi$ be constants to be determined.

First we got a integral equation $$\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sin c(x-y)}{\pi(x-y)}\psi(y)dy=\lambda\psi(x),\qquad|x|\le1.\tag{1}$$

Next, we got a differential equation $$\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^2)\frac{d\varphi}{dx}+(\chi-c^2x^2)\varphi=0.\tag{2}$$

For every real $x$, we further define an operator $P_x$ by $$P_x=\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}-c^2x^2.$$

The author claimed that, the operator $P_x$ commutes with the kernel of the integral operator above, which means, $$P_x\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sin c(x-y)}{\pi(x-y)}r(y)dy=\int_{-1}^1\frac{\sin c(x-y)}{\pi(x-y)}P_yr(y)dy$$ for all $r(y)\in L^2(-1,1)$ and all real $x$.

**My first problem is how to prove that they commute with each other.**

And then the author claimed that, every solution to $(1)$ is also a solution to $(2)$, I can not prove this too.

**My second problem is how to prove that every solution to $(1)$ is also a solution to $(2)$.**

**My attempt for the second problem:** I tried to plug $(1)$ into the left hand side of $(2)$, and to see if it was equal to $0$. But after plugging it in, many quotients involving $sin$ and $cos$ came out, which make the terms very ugly and let me hard to go on.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you do it for $r\in C^2$?

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry I can’t... Otherwise if I can work out the case of $C^2$, then I can do the case of $L^2$ by approximation right?

Comment: Almost, you need to be careful for general $r\in L^2$ because then $P_yr(y)$ is actually a distribution.

Comment: @user10354138 I see. But can you help me out the case of $C^2$? Thank you so much.

Comment: Sorry, but could you explain what do you mean by $\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}-c^2x^2$? Do you literally mean the derivative of $(1-x^2)$? It's just new notation for me. Also note that that your integral equation is defined by a continuous kernel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator. Also, where those $\chi$ appear?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. $[\frac{d}{dx}(1-x^2)\frac{d}{dx}-c^2x^2]f(x):=\frac{d}{dx}[(1-x^2)\frac{df(x)}{dx}]-c^2x^2f(x)$ And $\chi$ appears in $(2)$.

Comment: Yeah, the kernel is a self-adjoint compact operator and we can apply the spectrum theorem to $(1)$. But I feel like this observation doesn't help in my questions.